# A database with PAO (period after opening) by beauty product

Tags: data-request

I'm working on an app and I'm looking for a open database with [PAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period-after-opening_symbol) (period after opening) by cosmetic product of worldwide beauty brands.